# Javascript detect event handlers available on HTML element

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events, onload

Is there a way to detect what event handlers are available natively for an HTML element?

For example:

```
isAvailable(img.onload) === true;    // All browsers
isAvailable(script.onload) === true; // Non-IE only (Webkit, Firefox, Opera)
isAvailable(link.onload) === true;   // IE (and I think Opera) only
```

Ideally I want to do feature detection in my script, where if `onload` is available for an element to use that, otherwise fallback. Currently I am having to do browser forks (based on IE) which is annoying as IE may start supporting `script.onload`, and Webkit/Firefox may start supporting `link.onload`.

Unfortunately assigning `element.onload` makes the event no longer 'undefined', regardless of whether it will eventually fire or not.

Answer (score 0):

(**Edit** See below, this doesn't work.) You can check whether the element has an `onload` property:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
alert("img onload? " + ('onload' in img));
var script = document.createElement('script');
alert("script onload? " + ('onload' in script));
```

On IE7, I get `true` for the `img`, and `false` for the `script`.

**Edit** This doesn't work for Firefox. Leaving this just so others don't go down the same path.

Comment: Thanks, that is a novel test but as you say: no bananas!

Comment: @mummybot: Yeah, I was disapopinted. :-( There are lots of other things you can test in a similar way, but apparently not this. You can always feature-test by adding elements temporarily and seeing if they fire the event, but that may well be overkill.

Comment: Also fraught because you would have to make the assumption that if the tested for element had not fired after an indeterminate period it therefore does not support onload. You wouldn't be able to check if a server went down or the internets were just going slow. Plus this would add in quite a delay... gah :(

Comment: @mummybot: I was thinking in terms of loading from a data URI (no 'net delay involved). Nearly all browsers support data URIs now. (http://html5readiness.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you were asking for, but this will let you know if you have a specific method or property available for a given object.

```
var apple = new Object;
    apple.load = function() { alert("I am a method.") };
    apple.color = "red"

function isAvailable(obj, mp) { 
    // obj = element to test for method or property. 
    // mp = name of method or property. 

    if (obj[mp]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isAvailable(apple, "color")) {
    alert("apple object has a 'color' property");
}

if (isAvailable(apple, "load")) {
    alert("apple object has a 'load' method");
}
```

**Edit:** Re-worked the answer to show an example.

Comment: Thanks John but no. I am specifically looking to detect if a DOM object has a particular method (load), not javascript objects in general. I am pretty sure that this is not possible.

Comment: I reworked my answer to show that it finds a method or property in an object, not if an object exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before; when writing stuff for phone gap on the iphone, depending if you run the app in the simulator or on different versions of the device, you often have different handlers for handling the click of input buttons (and most other things)- so at the top of my script i just do a quick check;

```
var m_clickEvent = ''; 

if ( $('input').click != 'undefined')
   m_clickEvent = 'click'
else if ( $('input').tap != 'tap')
   m_clickEvent = 'tap'
else if ( $('input').touchstart!= 'touchstart')
   m_clickEvent = 'touchstart'
else 
   // some kind of error handling..
```

then i can go ahead and bind my event handler;

```
$('.myButton').bind(m_clickEvent, function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Hi Shawson, thanks for your reply, unfortunately there doesn't appear to be that option for onload handlers (re my original question) - "Unfortunately assigning element.onload makes the event no longer 'undefined', regardless of whether it will eventually fire or not."

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example destilled from the way [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) does event detection:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('script'); 
tmp.setAttribute('onload', '');
isSupported = typeof tmp.onload == 'function';
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works as you have copied it up there. The following code in the Firefox console says that the element cheese will have an onload event: 
var tmp = document.createElement('cheese');  
tmp.setAttribute('onload', '');  
console.log(tmp, tmp.onload);  
isSupported = typeof tmp.onload === 'function';  
console.log(isSupported);

Comment: Interesting. Well, maybe Firefox supports 'load' event listeners on all elements although there is no way to load content and thereby trigger it ;). I'd call this a bug in Firefox actually. The code works fine in Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've done this in the past is to use the old "for in" loop, and check each key value to see if it starts with "on" (every native event handler I've ever seen starts this way...) So, for example:

```
var el = document.querySelector("*"), //this is the element (use whatever selector text)
elEventHandlers = [];                 //set up an array to hold 'em all

for (var prop in el)                  //loop through each prop of the element
    if (prop.substring(0,2)=="on")    //if the prop starts with "on" it's an event handler
        elEventHandlers.push(prop);   //so, add it to the array

console.log(elEventHandlers);         //then dump the array to the console (or whatever)
```

voila! Now you know what event handlers can be registered on that element!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');

if(d.hasOwnProperty('onclick')) {
    //then onclick is supported
}
```

you could also loop through div's(or take any other HTML element) properties to dynamically check it:

```
var d = document.createElement('div'),
   el = 0;

for(el in d) {
    if(d.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
        console.log(d[el]); //or do anything else you like
    }
}
```

You could check more on hasOwnProperty on [mozilla's dev blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

```
isEventSupported =
    function(tag, event){
    return document.createElement(tag)[event]===null;
    };

>> isEventSupported("script", "onload"); 
true //on my current browser
```

There are, false reports on this event support even from veterans like..., let's not mention names - but it is NOT obvious that the onload event will most probably not fire on IMG elements SCRIPT elements and similar, because the source has already been cashed and Elements whose resources are being drawn from the cash will not fire the onload event.

Exception: the document element will fire the onload event, even when working with cashed files, because it depends on readystate complete.